# Convert tensorflow tensor of ASCII codes to string

Tags: python, ascii, tensorflow

I am quite new to tensorflow, and I couldn't find what I wanted on tensorflow.org or online discussions.

I have a tensor of ASCII codes I would like to convert to a string (each tensor is a word).

In numpy I could just iterate and use chr(), but tensor object is not iterable.

Is there a function that operates on the whole tensor, or a method that does not require evaluation?

Thanks!

Python 3.6.1 and Tensorflow 1.2.1

Comment: perhaps `tf.py_func` and use numpy method inside?

Comment: Yes, that is a good option. Thanks. This function is very usefull. Not sure why I never saw it before.